# Best way to turn a Lists of Eithers into an Either of Lists?

Tags: scala, either

I have some code like the below, where I have a list of Eithers, and I want to turn it into an Either of Lists ... in particular (in this case), if there are any Lefts in the list, then I return a Left of the list of them, otherwise I return a Right of the list of the rights.

```
val maybe: List[Either[String, Int]] = getMaybe
val (strings, ints) = maybe.partition(_.isLeft)
strings.map(_.left.get) match {
  case Nil => Right(ints.map(_.right.get))
  case stringList => Left(stringList)
}
```

Calling `get` always makes me feel like I must be missing something.

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: I find the described problem a bit wierd. The preference of the Strings over the Ints seems a bit asymetric. How about writing something like unzipEither, that returns both a list of strings and a list of ints. This way the method doesn't lose information, which your version does in case of a mixed list.

Comment: Sounds like you would maybe be better off using a structure like [Scalaz Validation](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/5465).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
data.partition(_.isLeft) match {                            
  case (Nil,  ints) => Right(for(Right(i) <- ints) yield i)        
  case (strings, _) => Left(for(Left(s) <- strings) yield s)
}
```

For one pass:

```
data.partition(_.isLeft) match {                            
  case (Nil,  ints) => Right(for(Right(i) <- ints.view) yield i)        
  case (strings, _) => Left(for(Left(s) <- strings.view) yield s)
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that is arguably more clear.  This seems to do more work, though. It's a pity you can't do this in a single pass.

Comment: You can do it in one pass if you use views instead of List for the resulting type, see my edit.

Comment: I think I have to give the .view trick the prize -- thx Viktor.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it should?

Answer (score 16):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, most collections are now provided with a [`partitionMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partitionMap%5BA1,A2%5D(f:A=%3EEither%5BA1,A2%5D):(CC%5BA1%5D,CC%5BA2%5D)) method which partitions elements based on a function returning either `Right` or `Left`.

In our case, we don't even need a function that transforms our input into `Right` or `Left` to define the partitioning since we already have `Right`s and `Left`s. Thus a simple use of `identity`!

Then it's just a matter of matching the resulting partitioned tuple of lefts and rights based on whether or not there are any lefts:

```
eithers.partitionMap(identity) match {
  case (Nil, rights) => Right(rights)
  case (lefts, _)    => Left(lefts)
}
// * List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(3), Left("error x"), Right(7))
//         => Either[List[String],List[Int]] = Left(List(error x))
// * List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(3), Right(7))
//         => Either[List[String],List[Int]] = Right(List(3, 7))
```

For the understanding of `partitionMap` here is the result of the intermediate step:

```
List(Right(3), Left("error x"), Right(7)).partitionMap(identity)
// (List[String], List[Int]) = (List(error x), List(3, 7))
```

Answer (score 11):

Solution from Functional Programming in Scala book.

```
def sequence[E,A](es: List[Either[E,A]]): Either[E,List[A]] = 
    traverse(es)(x => x)

def traverse[E,A,B](es: List[A])(f: A => Either[E, B]): Either[E, List[B]] = 
    es match {
      case Nil => Right(Nil)
      case h::t => (f(h) map2 traverse(t)(f))(_ :: _)
    }
def map2[EE >: E, B, C](a: Either[E, A], b: Either[EE, B])(f: (A, B) => C): 
   Either[EE, C] = for { a1 <- a; b1 <- b } yield f(a1,b1)
```

Comment: `traverse` can be written using `foldRight` as well

Answer (score 6):

```
val list = List(Left("x"),Right(2), Right(4))
val strings = for (Left(x) <- list) yield(x)
val result = if (strings.isEmpty) Right(for (Right(x) <- list) yield(x)) 
             else Left(strings)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write a generalized version of `split` as follows:

```
def split[X, CC[X] <: Traversable[X], A, B](l : CC[Either[A, B]])
   (implicit bfa : CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, CC[A]], bfb : CanBuildFrom[Nothing, B, CC[B]]) : (CC[A], CC[B]) = {
  def as = {
    val bf = bfa()
    bf ++= (l collect { case Left(x) => x})
    bf.result
  }

  def bs = {
    val bf = bfb()
    bf ++= (l collect { case Right(x) => x})
    bf.result
  }

  (as, bs)
}
```

Such that:

```
scala> List(Left("x"),Right(2), Right(4)) : List[Either[java.lang.String,Int]]
res11: List[Either[java.lang.String,Int]] = List(Left(x), Right(2), Right(4))

scala> split(res11)
res12: (List[java.lang.String], List[Int]) = (List(x),List(2, 4))

scala> Set(Left("x"),Right(2), Right(4)) : Set[Either[java.lang.String,Int]]
res13: Set[Either[java.lang.String,Int]] = Set(Left(x), Right(2), Right(4))

scala> split(res13)
res14: (Set[java.lang.String], Set[Int]) = (Set(x),Set(2, 4))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not create `as` and `bs` as vals?

Answer (score 3):

I kind of don't want any karma for this as it's a merge of [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491530/463761) and Viktor's from [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-user/12a3nvhmhj/splitting-either#20121003kruys7dxqz6xla6mebzaj6ms34).. but here's an alternative:

```
def split[CC[X] <: Traversable[X], A, B](xs: CC[Either[A, B]])
   (implicit bfa: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, CC[A]], bfb: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, B, CC[B]]) : (CC[A], CC[B]) =
  xs.foldLeft((bfa(), bfb())) {
    case ((as, bs), l@Left(a)) => (as += a, bs)
    case ((as, bs), r@Right(b)) => (as, bs += b)
  } match {
    case (as, bs) => (as.result(), bs.result())
  }
```

Example:

```
scala> val eithers: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Left("Hi"), Right(1))
eithers: List[Either[String,Int]] = List(Left(Hi), Right(1))

scala> split(eithers)
res0: (List[String], List[Int]) = (List(Hi),List(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have something more general and also functional then `Validated` from cats library is the type you might want. It is something like `Either` that can aggregate Errors. And in combination with `NonEmptyList` it can be really powerful.

http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html

Answer (score 1):

Isn't a more elegant way?

```
  def flatten[E,A](es: List[Either[E,A]]): Either[E,List[A]] = {
    @tailrec
    def go(tail: List[Either[E,A]], acc: List[A]): Either[E,List[A]] = tail match {
      case Nil  => Right(acc)
      case h::t => h match {
        case Left(e)  => Left(e)
        case Right(a) => go(t, a :: acc)
      }
    }
    go(es, Nil) map { _ reverse }
  }
```

- tail recursion
- one pass, assuming the `a :: acc` is a bullet-fast
- but still, reverse in the end
- `partitionMap`, is probably faster, because of internal implementation based on builder
- but this one is the lasy. You will get Left immediately.

Answer (score 0):

To extract Lefts and Rights separately:

```
val data: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(
  Right(1), 
  Left("Error #1"), 
  Right(42), 
  Left("Error #2")
)


val numbers: List[Int] = data.collect { case Right(value) => value }
val errors: List[String] = data.collect { case Left(error) => error }


println(numbers) // List(1, 42)
println(errors)  // List(Error #1, Error #2)
```