# Efficient and/or idiomatic way to turn Seq[Either[String, Int]] to (Seq[String], Seq[Int])

Tags: scala, either

Slightly simplifying, my problem comes from a list of strings `input` that I want to parse with a function `parse` returning `Either[String,Int]`.

Then `list.map(parse)` returns a list of `Either`s. The next step in the program is to format an error message summing up all the errors *or* passing on the list of parsed integers.

Lets call the solution I'm looking for `partitionEithers`.

Calling

```
partitionEithers(List(Left("foo"), Right(1), Left("bar")))
```

Would give

```
(List("foo", "bar"),List(1))
```

Finding something like this in the standard library would be best. Failing that some kind of clean, idiomatic and efficient solution would be best. Also some kind of efficient utility function I could just paste into my projects would be ok.

I was very confused between [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230999/how-to-reduce-a-seqeithera-b-to-a-eithera-seqb) 3 [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608799/how-to-convert-from-seq-of-either-to-either-of-a-seq-scala?lq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489584/best-way-to-turn-a-lists-of-eithers-into-an-either-of-lists). As far as I can tell, neither of those questions matches my case, but some answers there seem to contain valid answers to this question.

Comment: Did you mean "*or* passing on the list of parsed integers", or "*and*"? If it's really *or*, then you need an `Either[Seq[String], Seq[Int]]`, and not a `(Seq[String], Seq[Int])`.

Comment: @dcastro :D you are right. Thanks! I was even more confused than I suspected. I'm leaving the question here in case someone actually needs what I asked for and since there are already multiple answers.

Comment: @PeterLamberg - Incidentally, if you care about speed, your solution was fastest by a sizable margin.

Comment: @RexKerr Good to know :) I was imagining what this could look like if it was a library function and I appreciate optimized library functions. I also tried to generalize on the collection type based on this [answer by oxbow_lakes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6491530/1148030), but I wasn't satisfied with the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a List\[Either\[A, B\]\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576530/how-to-split-a-listeithera-b)

Comment: @PeterNeyens yup, it really seems like my question is a dupe. I wonder why I couldn't find "How to split a List[Either[A, B]]". I think I really tried. Perhaps I failed to use the keyword "split". I'll think about this a bit and close this question soon.

Comment: @PeterLamberg I don't know if it needs to be actually closed. There is some interesting information in the comments thanks to Rex Kerr and we got some different answers (like yours) along with some similar (like mine :-) ). I just thought it was a good idea to link the 2 questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really get the amount of contortions of the other answers. So here is a one liner:

```
scala> val es:List[Either[Int,String]] = 
           List(Left(1),Left(2),Right("A"),Right("B"),Left(3),Right("C"))
es: List[Either[Int,String]] = List(Left(1), Left(2), Right(A), Right(B), Left(3), Right(C))

scala> es.foldRight( (List[Int](), List[String]()) ) { 
         case ( e, (ls, rs) ) => e.fold( l => ( l :: ls, rs), r => ( ls, r :: rs ) ) 
       }
res5: (List[Int], List[String]) = (List(1, 2, 3),List(A, B, C))
```

Comment: This is 3x slower than the OP's collections-internals-like implementation, by the way.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "3x" instead of something vague.

Comment: Anything more sophisticated than subtracting timesptamps from before and after?

Comment: I used my rapid benchmarking tool, Thyme (on a list of length 100,000 with approximately equal numbers of left and right cases).

Answer (score 7):

Scala collections offer a `partition` function:

```
val eithers: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Left("foo"), Right(1), Left("bar"))

eithers.partition(_.isLeft) match {
  case (leftList, rightList) =>
    (leftList.map(_.left.get), rightList.map(_.right.get))
}

=> res0: (List[String], List[Int]) = (List(foo, bar),List(1))
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to wrap it in a (maybe even somewhat type safer) generic function:

```
def partitionEither[Left : ClassTag, Right : ClassTag](in: List[Either[Left, Right]]): (List[Left], List[Right]) =
  in.partition(_.isLeft) match {
    case (leftList, rightList) =>
      (leftList.collect { case Left(l: Left) => l }, rightList.collect { case Right(r: Right) => r })
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant and not typesafe.  Partition doesn't understand that you're restricting the allowed types.

Comment: @RexKerr I am aware that `partition(_.isLeft)` does know that it partitions into Lefts and Rights. But the result should in real life be exactly that, shouldn't it? I am curious, would it be *typesafe* enough for a pragmatist or is there a scenario where it could actually fail? Also, I updated my answer, would that be more type safe?

Comment: In your update, the partition is doing exactly zero work.  The pair of `collect`s does everything, whether or not you partition in advance!  Anyway--yes, it might be okay for a pragmatist, but not for an idealist.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `separate` from `MonadPlus` (scalaz) or `MonadCombine` (cats) :

```
import scala.util.{Either, Left, Right}

import scalaz.std.list._
import scalaz.std.either._
import scalaz.syntax.monadPlus._

val l: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(1), Left("error"), Right(2))
l.separate  
// (List[String], List[Int]) = (List(error),List(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an imperative implementation mimicking the style of Scala collection internals.

I wonder if there should something like this in there, since at least I run into this from time to time.

```
import collection._
import generic._
def partitionEithers[L, R, E, I, CL, CR]
                    (lrs: I)
                    (implicit evI: I <:< GenTraversableOnce[E],
                              evE: E <:< Either[L, R],
                              cbfl: CanBuildFrom[I, L, CL],
                              cbfr: CanBuildFrom[I, R, CR])
                    : (CL, CR) = {
  val ls = cbfl()
  val rs = cbfr()

  ls.sizeHint(lrs.size)
  rs.sizeHint(lrs.size)

  lrs.foreach { e => evE(e) match {
    case Left(l)  => ls += l
    case Right(r) => rs += r
  } }

  (ls.result(), rs.result())
}

partitionEithers(List(Left("foo"), Right(1), Left("bar"))) == (List("foo", "bar"), List(1))
partitionEithers(Set(Left("foo"), Right(1), Left("bar"), Right(1))) == (Set("foo", "bar"), Set(1))
```

Comment: Thanks @HTNW for the generic collection handling. Impressive! I'm slightly worried that the signature is not very understandable now... perhaps adding some type bounds or tweaking the naming could help? (also adding back the sizeHints)

Answer (score 0):

You can use foldLeft.

```
  def f(s: Seq[Either[String, Int]]): (Seq[String], Seq[Int]) = {
    s.foldRight((Seq[String](), Seq[Int]())) { case (c, r) =>
      c match {
        case Left(le) => (le +: r._1, r._2)
        case Right(ri) => (r._1 , ri +: r._2)
      }
    }
  }

val eithers: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Left("foo"), Right(1), Left("bar"))

scala> f(eithers)
res0: (Seq[String], Seq[Int]) = (List(foo, bar),List(1))
```

Comment: This is a disaster used on `List`.  `:+` is O(n) in the length of the list, so it's an O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: @RexKerr: True. I changed it and used a prepend (+:) which is a constant operation.