# Converting a list of either to a cats ValidatedNel

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Given:

```
def convert[T](list: List[Either[String, T]]): Validated[NonEmptyList[String], NonEmptyList[T]] =
  NonEmptyList.fromList(list)
    .toRight("list is empty")
    .flatMap(...
```

How do I flat map the `NonEmptyList[Either[String, T]]` so ultimately I end up with my `Validated` return value?

Is there anything in the `cats` library to account for this scenario? Or do I need to do this manually following something like: [Best way to turn a Lists of Eithers into an Either of Lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489584/best-way-to-turn-a-lists-of-eithers-into-an-either-of-lists)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd write this as follows:

```
import cats.data.{ NonEmptyList, Validated, ValidatedNel }
import cats.instances.list._, cats.syntax.list._
import cats.syntax.either._
import cats.syntax.option._
import cats.syntax.traverse._

def convert[T](list: List[Either[String, T]]): ValidatedNel[String, NonEmptyList[T]] =
  list.traverse(_.toValidatedNel).andThen(_.toNel.toValidNel("list is empty"))
```

First we flip the whole thing inside out while transforming the `Either`s to `Validated`s (with `traverse` and `toValidatedNel`), to get a `ValidatedNel[String, List[T]]`, and then we handle the case where the result is empty (with `andThen` and `toNel`).

The `andThen` is probably one of the pieces you're missing—it's essentially `flatMap` for `Validated` (but without the implications and syntactic sugar baggage that `flatMap` brings). If you wanted you could probably pretty easily change my version to do the empty list check first, as in your sketch, but the way I've written it feels a little more natural to me.

Footnote: I have no idea why the enrichment method for `Option` is named `toValidNel` while the one for `Either` is `toValidatedNel`—I hadn't noticed this before, probably because I hadn't used them in the same line before. This seems unfortunate, especially since we're stuck with it for a while now that Cats 1.0 is out.

Another footnote: note that you'll need the `-Ypartial-unification` compiler option enabled for `traverse` to work without type parameters if you're on 2.11.

Comment: In reference to the footnote, for anyone reading. I am using Scala 2.12 but needed to enable "Experimental Features" in the Intellij Scala compiler settings.