# How to break RxJava chain on error Result?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I've inherited this codebase which uses RxJava2 and kotlin with a rather peculiar Result pattern for API calls. i.e. all API calls return Singles with a Result object (which is a sealed class of Success and Error types as shown below) i.e.

```
sealed class Result<T, E> {
    data class Success<T, E>(
            val data: T
    ): Result<T, E>()

    data class Error<T, E>(
            val error: E
    ): Result<T, E>()
}
```

Now I'm trying to chain together a bunch of API calls of these but need to terminate the chain on the first Result.Error in it and continue if not.

The only way I can think of is to zip all of the Singles and then have a zipper function that checks the type of each parameter and returns a `Result.Error()` with the first error it encounters. i.e. something like,

```
Singles.zip(
    repo1.makeCall1(arg),
    repo1.makeCall2(arg2),
    repo2.makeCall1(arg3)
) { result1, result2, result3 ->
    val data1 = when (result1) {
        is Result.Error -> return@zip Result.Error(result1.error)
        is Result.Success -> result1.data
    }
    val data2 = when (result2) {
        is Result.Error -> return@zip Result.Error(result2.error)
        is Result.Success -> result2.data
    }
    val data3 = when (result3) {
        is Result.Error -> return@zip Result.Error(result3.error)
        is Result.Success -> result3.data
    }

    return@zip Result.Success(MergedData(data1, data2, data3))
}
```

which works but looks really weird (and feels like a code smell with this huge ass zipper method). Also does not allow me to chain anything more after the last method (that checks if the Result is a Success / Error).

I feel it would be a lot more readable to be able to chain these calls and terminate on the first error but I don't know enough Rx to do this. Is there an operator or an approach that could help make this better?

Answer (score 1):

You can get original `Single` behavior by reversing what your codebase already does.

Create transformer which will extract data from api call or throw error on error. First error will terminate `zip`.

```
public <T, E extends Throwable> SingleTransformer<Result<T, E>, T> transform() {
    return source -> source.flatMap(result -> {
        if (result instanceof Result.Success) 
            return Single.just(((Success<T, E>) result).getData());
          else
            return Single.error(((Error<T, E>) result).getError());
    });
}
```

Use it with `repo.makeCall(arg).compose(transform())`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, this is the most rx-like way to handle this; we've been using a similar pattern for some specific retrofit calls that return results.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, RxJava would "abort on the first error" because Observable and Single (which is akin to `Task`/`Future`/`Promise`) has "monadic qualities". But as `Result<*, *>` explicitly makes errors be handled on the "success" path to avoid aborting the stream, we might want to consider a different route than letting Rx go to terminal events - because the existing code expects it to be on the success path. Terminal events should be for "the world is ending" exceptions, not ones we actually expect and can handle.

---

I had some ideas but I think the only thing you can do is *reduce the number of lines it takes to do this* instead of flat-out removing it.

Technically we are trying to re-implement the [`Either<E, T>` monad here from Arrow](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/7b2c51311ac12a818ae7555b2abbaa52f11b20f7/modules/core/arrow-core/src/main/kotlin/arrow/core/Either.kt#L15), but knowing that, we can reduce the number of lines with some tricks:

```
sealed class Result<T, E>(
    open val error: E? = null,
    open val data: T? = null
) {
    data class Success<T>(
        override val data: T
    ): Result<T, Nothing?>()

    data class Error<E>(
        override val error: E
    ): Result<Nothing?, E>()
}

fun <E> E.wrapWithError(): Result.Error<E> = Result.Error(this) // similar to `Either.asLeft()`
fun <T> T.wrapWithSuccess(): Result.Success<T> = Result.Success(this)  // similar to `Either.asRight()`

fun blah() {
    Singles.zip(
        repo1.makeCall1(arg),
        repo1.makeCall2(arg2),
        repo2.makeCall1(arg3)
    ) { result1, result2, result3 ->
        val data1 = result1.data ?: return@zip result1.error.wrapWithError()
        val data2 = result2.data ?: return@zip result2.error.wrapWithError()
        val data3 = result3.data ?: return@zip result3.error.wrapWithError()

        Result.Success(MergedData(data1, data2, data3))
    }
}
```

Comment: would not merge work better here, OP wants to terminate on first error?

Comment: Merge would run on each completion, he wants to complete only after all 3 are done. Although now that you mention it, this means that `call2` and `call3` could happen even if `call1` failed... maybe this should really be a `flatMap` chain, basically what [Rx comprehensions](https://github.com/pakoito/Komprehensions/blob/8c258854644e76df0c34ec2ebfba7c188b56ba9a/komprehensions-rx2/src/main/kotlin/com/pacoworks/komprehensions/rx2/KomprehensionsRx.kt#L59) do. I was so focused on codegolfing the `when` statement that I didn't think about it. ¬¬ keeping the errors on the success path is tricky.

Comment: I'd also like to be able to do more stuff with the data. For e.g. use a value from data2 to then decide if we need to make another couple API calls, which currently means all of this will also have to be inside the zipper function :(

Comment: Actually, my comment here about using tuples was wrong. This is *very* tricky.

Comment: sorry about that (the example above was meant to be illustrative - there could be several more of these calls in some cases 6 or more)

Comment: Ah. In that case I'm not well-versed enough at this particular moment. All I know is that you're trying to solve the problem of flattening a `Future<TupleN<Either<E, A>, Either<E, B>, ..., Either<E, N>>>` into a `Future<Either<E, TupleN<A, B, .., N>>>`. I wonder how you can do that, I don't remember. >.< apparently [this is how you do it in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6490882/2413303), but that's not really helping

Comment: Maybe you just need an extension function that does this whole `error vs success` dance for 1 to N arity, and tuples classes from 1 to N arity, and then you'd have an `Either<E, TupleN<...>>` to work with, on which you can `fold` or `mapRight` and stuff. I dunno I am getting confused because I'm not that well-versed in functional style.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this code block:

```
Single.zip(
        Single.just(Result.Error(error = 9)),
        Single.just(Result.Success(data = 10)),
        Single.just(Result.Success(data = 11)),
        Function3<Result<Int, Int>, Result<Int, Int>, Result<Int, Int>, List<Result<Int, Int>>> { t1, t2, t3 ->
            mutableListOf(t1, t2, t3)
        })
        .map { list ->
            list.forEach {
                if (it is Result.Error){
                    return@map it
                }
            }
            return@map Result
        } // or do more chain here.
        .subscribe()
```

I combine the results into a `list`, then map it to your expected result. It's much easier to read.

Comment: that does make the check for errors at the start however we'd still need to do it again to get the actual values I think?

Comment: @Bootstrapper I do not quite understand your argument. You can just return@map `Result.Success(MergedData(data1, data2, data3)`. The readableness here is much important than small optimization.

Comment: could you please share how you would get the data1, data2, data3 values?